# Bundle.js and Css file are not getting load with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I recently learned react and webpack.I got into a problem while making my project.

When I am opening index.html.In browser network it is showing bundle.js not found..and also I cant see CSS files. please help me.

I don't know why my files are not showing in the network.
My all files got successfully bundled.

Please help me out where my code is wrong.

My folder structure

```
node modules
app-(contains js jsx and css files)
public- (contains single bundle file.There is no bundle.js.map file)
package.json
package-lock.json
webpack.config.js
index.html
```

my webpack config

```
var path=require("path");

module.exports={
    entry:path.resolve(__dirname,"app"),

    output:{
    path:path.resolve(__dirname,"public"),
    filename:" bundle.js",
    },

    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.jsx?$/,
                include:path.resolve(__dirname,"app"),
                use:[{loader:'babel-loader',

                     options: {
                                 presets: ['@babel/preset-react',{
                          'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']}]
                             }
                     }]
            },
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                include:path.resolve(__dirname,"app"),
                use:["style-loader","css-loader"]
            }

        ]

    }

};
```

my package .json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodeman": "^1.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="public/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the `bundle.js` file in the `public` folder? If not, you need to run the build.

Comment: Yes I have that in public.It got successfully build but not showing file (not found bundle.js)

Comment: Because the quote is in the wrong spot when defining your bundle's filename and you have a space within the string: `filename:" bundle.js"`. You are creating  `bundle.js` with a leading space.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the path of bundle.js to ***src="/public/bundle.js"***  inside the index.html file may resolve the problem.

**Explanation:**

The script tag specifies the location of bundle.js file as

***src="public/bundle.js"***

This path does not have a leading "/". Therefore, the path will be interpreted relative to the location of the current file being read by the browser.

Adding a leading / to the path will make the browser request the script file from a path relative to document root.